# Why can't I get 'grunt-browser-sync' to work with jekyll?

Tags: gruntjs, jekyll

I am trying to set up a workflow using grunt, to help with development of my jekyll site.

Found this great [TUT](http://quick.as/5g9c1jx) which basically goes through how to install it in your workflow.

However, I get these errors when I run the 'grunt' command.

```
**[BS] Warning: Multiple External IP addresses found**
**[BS] If you have problems, you may need to manually set the 'host' option**
**[BS] Server running. Use this URL: http://192.168.1.5:3005**
[BS] Serving files from: /Users/antonioortiz/Sites/newaortiz/_site
**[BS] Not watching any files...**
[BS] Browser Connected! (Chrome, version: 33.0.1750.146)
```

Obviously the ones I bolded are most glaring, as NO css is being generated in my 'assets/css
Below is my Gruntfile. Thank you in advance.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-jekyll');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browser-sync');


// All configuration goes here
grunt.initConfig({

    jekyll: {
        build: {
            dest: '_site'
        }
    },

    sass: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                'assets/css/*.css': 'assets/sass/*.scss'
            }
        }
    },
    compass: {
        dev: {
            options: {
                config: 'config.rb'
            } //options
        } // dist
    }, //compass

    watch: {
        sass: {
            files: 'assets/**/*.scss',
            tasks: ['sass']
        },
        jekyll: {
            files: ['_layouts/*.html', '_includes/*.md', 'assets/css/*.css'],
            tasks: ['jekyll']
        }
    },
    compass: {
            files: ['assets/sass/*.scss'],
            tasks: ['compass:dev']
        }, // sass

    browser_sync: {
        files: {
            src: ['_site/assets/css/*.css']
        },
        options: {
            watchTask: true,
            ghostMode: {
                clicks: true,
                scroll: true,
                links: true,
                forms: true
            },
            server: {
                baseDir: '_site'
            }
        }
    }

});



// Custom tasks
grunt.registerTask('build', ['sass', 'jekyll']);
grunt.registerTask('default', ['build', 'browser_sync', 'watch']);
};
```

Comment: Just wondering if there's anything I need to add to help?  :)

Comment: Did you watch for the indentation? Javascript is very picky there. The closing curly braces seem to not line up correctly (also see <https://github.com/stevekwan/best-practices/blob/master/javascript/best-practices.md>). I just completed the tutorial and got it working here as advertised – had some issues myself since I'm not a Javascript expert and just started using grunt (I set up my sass dir this way `path1/path2/**/*.scss` instead of just `**/*.scss` – now the watching function works).